# How to add new object to NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder how can I add an new item on `NSMutableArray` in each button click. I already did `addObject`("something") in button action. The result is always something the `object.count` still 1. What I want is in each click the object on `NSMutableArray` adding.

Right now the result I get is like below: 
This when I clicked three times

```
(something)(something)(something)
```

But the result that I want is like this

```
(something,something,something)
```

when I clicked 5 times

```
(something,something,something,something,something)
```

... and so on

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func press(sender: UIButton) {
    var mutar : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    mutar.addObject("something")
    println(mutar)
}
```

Comment: because each press new array did initial! so in array still has one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are allocating the array every time whenever you press the button. It will always get reduced to count 0 on allocation.

Keep this line out of the IBAction method and add it to **viewDidLoad()**:

```
var mutar : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

Comment: The variable needs to be visible for the IBAction though.. Add it as an instance variable instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your array as an instance variable of your class.

At the top of your class, put:

```
var array = NSMutableArray()
```

You are currently initializing an array and adding one object to it, each time you click the button, hence you only have one object each time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that when you click the button it will create new `NSMutableArray`

Create `instance variable`

`var mutar : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`

```
@IBAction func press(sender: UIButton) {

      mutar.addObject("something")


     println(mutar)
}
```

Comment: That's an instance variable

Answer (score 0):

Create a global array and allocate memory only once either from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, In your case on every click you are allocating memory to that array then adding that object into array. So initialize and allocate memory only once and than add object on button click, you will get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my objective c code snippet:

```
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:string] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
if (array==nil)
    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:crctId, nil];
else if (![array containsObject:crctId]){
    flag = YES;
    if(crctId!=nil)
    {
        [array addObject:crctId];
    }
}
```